# Cannot evaluate module FacebookLib : Configuration with name 'debug' not found

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am getting this error when I run the command "cordova build android". 
I have the following lines of code in my "build.gradle" file in platforms/android directory:

```
debugCompile(
    project(
        path: "phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib", 
        configuration: "debug"
    )
)
releaseCompile(
    project(
        path: "phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib", 
        configuration: "release"
    )
)
```

In the same directory I have another file "settings.gradle" which have the following lines of code

```
include ":phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib"
project(":phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib").projectDir = new File("phonegap-facebook-plugin/app-FacebookLib")
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @RaxWeber Could youplease mention the steps you followed to add the facebook plugin? Because when i added it in my project using cordova CLI, all i could see is dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug")
    releaseCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release")
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
} in my build.gradle

Comment: @RaxWeber Seems more like an issue with plugin installation

Comment: @Gandhi I just followed the instructions provided in the repo's README. I suppose it's because of version irregularities in my project. However, I already resolved this issue by using another plugin. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41099136/cordova-android-build-failure-configuration-with-name-debug-not-found

Comment: @RaxWeber the one i was using is the same one which you mentioned - cordova-plugin-facebook4 If the issue is resolved, please take off the bounty or elaborate the question regd th actual plugin

Comment: @Gandhi I think there's no option to take off the bounty. It will automatically end in 5 days (from now).

Answer (score 1):

Hey I had the same thing. It was either adding the facebook plugin (as you have) or it was because i changed the name of my package from some auto generated package name "com.ionicframeword.appname123342" to "com.appname.appname" Either way Trick was to remove platforms with

```
cordova platforms rm android
```

then re-add

```
cordova platforms add android
```

Do that with all platforms that are giving you a head ache.