# Cordova Android Build Failure: Configuration with name 'debug' not found

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, facebook-android-sdk

After adding the [phonegap-facebook-plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) to my Cordova project, and building the project for android, it fails with the error:

> Cannot evaluate module FacebookLib : Configuration with name 'debug' not found

My android project structure looks like this:

```
android
  --> CordovaLib
        --> build.gradle
  --> phonegap-facebook-plugin
        --> chooze-FacebookLib
              --> build.gradle
  --> build.gradle
  --> settings.gradle
```

The root `build.gradle` file contains this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    debugCompile(project(path: "phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib", configuration: "release"))
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

And `settings.gradle`:

```
// GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT
include ":"
include ":CordovaLib"
include ":phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib"
project(":phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib").projectDir = new File("phonegap-facebook-plugin/chooze-FacebookLib")
```

I seem to not have found any solution that would solve this problem. I'd appreciate any suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying so many solutions, I have resolved the issue by using another plugin, which is the [cordova-plugin-facebook4](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4) — a forked version of the official plugin. Works like a charm!

Comment: Nice one! Did the same as you